# Can one perform trend analysis with ANOVA?

Tags: anova, contrasts

I'm using the *multcomp* package in *R* to do a trend test as part of an ANOVA.  I am wondering if it is possible to not only ask "is there a trend" within one of the treatments but also "are the trends *different*" between the 2 treatments? 
I'm using a means parametrization like

```
glm(response ~ -1 + treatment:factor(year), ...)
```

and the contrast matrix if feed to the glht function of multcomp looks like

```
"treat1.trend" = c(-2,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  2, 0)
"treat2.trend" = c( 0, -2,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0, 2)
```

Is it possible to test if the two trends are the same?  A wild guess would be something like:

```
"treat2.trend" = c( -2, -2,  -1, -1,  1,  1,  2, 2)
```